# Ambiguous reference error compiling Scala with Java 9

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, java-9

Currently I am facing the following compilation error in Scala against Java 9:

```
: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method putAll in class Properties of type (x$1: java.util.Map[_, _])Unit
and  method putAll in class Hashtable of type (x$1: java.util.Map[_ <: Object, _ <: Object])Unit
match argument types (java.util.Properties)
  newProps.putAll(props)
```

newProps is defined as:

```
  val newProps = new Properties
```

I tried variants of newProps.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[...]] but got different compilation errors.

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Did you try `newProps.asInstanceOf[java.util.Properties]`? It looks like it cannot tell if `newProps` is class `Properties` or class `Hashtable`.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10418

Answer (score 3):

As @Ted pointed out this is a known issue. One workardound would be to subsitute `putAll` with something like this:

```
props.forEach((k, v) => newProps.put(k, v))
```

Note that by doing this your operation is not atomic anymore but most probably this is not important in your case.

Comment: You can also use 'newProps ++= props'